# C# ASP.NET Core AutoMapper: Child object is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have a many to many relationship between Users and Accounts.

When I do an `HttpGet`, I want to return `AccountForDetailDto` which includes an `ICollection<UserForListDto>` to list the users attached to that account.

I get the User IDs of the users attached to the account, but the User objects are null.

I assume that I need to do an `Include` somewhere, but I'm not sure where.
I've tried `.Include(account => account.UserAccounts.Select(userAccounts => userAccounts.User)`.

Or am I missing a map/property of a map.

Here's what I've got:

#### AccountsController.cs

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetAccount")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAccount(int id)
{
    var accountFromRepo = await _repo.GetAccount(id);

    var accountToReturn = _mapper.Map<AccountForDetailedDto>(accountFromRepo);

    return Ok(accountToReturn);
}
```

#### AccountRepository.cs

```
public async Task<Account> GetAccount(int id)
{
    return await _context.Accounts
        .Include(a => a.UserAccounts)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == id);
}
```

#### AutoMapperProfiles.cs

```
CreateMap<UserAccount, UserForListDto>();

CreateMap<Account, AccountForDetailedDto>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Users, opt => opt.MapFrom(a => a.UserAccounts));
```

#### Models

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}

public class UserAccount
{
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public int? AccountId { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

#### Dtos

```
public class AccountForDetailedDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserForListDto> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserForListDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be that the first step is to do `.ThenInclude(ua => ua.User)` in `GetAccount(int id)`. But I'm still not getting the list of users in the returned `AccountForDetailedDto`

Comment: Then needed to change the AutoMapper profile to say `.ForMember(dto => dto.Users, opt => opt.MapFrom(a => a.UserAccounts.Select(ua => ua.User));`

Comment: And I don't need `CreateMap<UserAccount, UserForListDto>();` in the AutoMapper profile.